# How to count the number of times that a range does not match a cell

Tags: excel, countif

I am trying to count the number of times that a range does not match a cell.

For example: B5 can be "Yes" or "No" based on the selection from a Data Validation Table. I want the formula to count the number of times that C5:N5 do NOT match B5. So if B5 is "Yes", how many times in C5:N5 was "No" selected. And if B5 is "No", how many times in C5:N5 was "Yes" selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `COUNTIF` function:

```
=COUNTIF(C5:N5,"<>" & B5)
```

This function will return the number of cells in `C5:N5` that does not equal the value in cell `B5`.

Comment: That was a very fast answer! And it worked to perfection. Thanks so much!